# Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'?

Tags: python, linked-list

Below is my code in python. I'm basically trying to look through a linked list to see if a specific element is in that list. The code works if the item is in the list, but not if it doesn't. I believe the problem lies within the loop coming to the end of the list and the last node, but I'm not sure how to fix the error. Any help would be appreciated. (Edited to include the classes used)

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):

        #raise error for wrong data input type
        if not type(data) in [int, float, str]:
            raise TypeError("data must be an integer, float, or string")

        self.value = data


class LinkedListNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, data):



        Node.__init__(self, data)       # Use inheritance to set self.value.
        self.next = None                # Reference to the next node.
        self.prev = None                # Reference to the previous node.



class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.length = 0

    def append(self, data):

        # Create a new node to store the input data.
        new_node = LinkedListNode(data)
        if self.head is None:
            # If the list is empty, assign the head and tail attributes to
            # new_node, since it becomes the first and last node in the list.
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            self.length += 1
        else:
            # If the list is not empty, place new_node after the tail.
            self.tail.next = new_node               # tail --> new_node
            new_node.prev = self.tail               # tail <-- new_node
            # Now the last node in the list is new_node, so reassign the tail.
            self.tail = new_node
            self.length += 1


    def find(self, data):

        x = range(self.length)
        current_position = self.head.value
        current_node = self.head

        for i in x:
            if current_position == data:
                return self.head
            else:
                current_node = current_node.next
                current_position = current_node.value


        if current_position != data:
            raise ValueError("data point is not in the list")

        return
```

Comment: there seems to be indentation errors in your could.
Could you please fix them,, so that we're sure to see the same code, that you execute?

Also the parameter self seems to indicate, that you implemented a class.

So it would be interesting to see how you mark the end if a linked list.

Is it, that `node.next == None` or do yuou have another condition.

We might be able to see that if you also posted the `__init__()` method of this class

Comment: because you `current_node` is `None`. Add one more condition before check if the current position is data

Comment: Normally the whole point of traversing a linked list is, that you do not have to know how many elements are in a linked list.
So instead of `for i in x:` you might just write:
`while current_node is not None:`

Comment: Agreeing with @gelonida: The point of a singly-linked list is to use the constraints of *only* having access to the node's data and to the next node. If you work with additional information like length of the list or iterate over the list in a for loop, then you are not implementing a linked list.

Comment: What other condition would I need to add? The only thing that I could think of is if the list was empty. @Mr_U4913

Comment: @gelonida already gives the solution like using `while`, or adding `if current_node is not None: do something`